# Bootstrap fix form to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to fix this form to the bottom of the page can somebody help?

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
     </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: `position: fixed; bottom: 0`?

Comment: Do you mean a footer?

Comment: What did you try? Show some attempt please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the CSS to position the form to the bottom.

```css
form {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
         </div>
      </form>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would it stay fixed in the bottom even if user scroll in the page? something like fixed even when scroll?

Comment: @Developer I've edited it to be fixed even when it scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
     </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form>
      <div class="form-group fixed-bottom">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: fixed-bottom class?

Comment: Yes, its a bootstrap class. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/